# Laravel aggregate sum by id not showing on Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sum, aggregate-functions, laravel-blade

I have developed an inventory management system where the products table and order_details table are available. Now I want to show how many products are sold according to product_id and the summing amount to show on the blade template loop. Where Product table ID equal to order_details product_id. But unfortunately, it's not showing.

The Product Controller index Function

```
public function index()
{
    $orderdetail = DB::table('order_details')
            ->select('quantity', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as sum'))
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->havingRaw('SUM(quantity)')
            ->get();

    $products = Product::latest()->with('category', 'supplier', 'orderdetail')->get();
    return view('admin.product.index', compact('products', 'orderdetail'));

}
```

The Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $dates = [
        'buying_date', 'expire_date',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
    }

    public function orderdetail()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderDetail', 'id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

and the Blade

```
@foreach($products as $key => $product)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    <td>
        <img class="img-rounded" style="height:35px; width: 35px;" src="{{ URL::asset("storage/product/".$product->image) }}" alt="{{ $product->name }}">
    </td>
    <td>{{ $product->category->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->supplier->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->code }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->buying_date->toFormattedDateString() }}</td>
    <td>{{ number_format($product->buying_price, 2) }}</td>
    <td>{{ number_format($product->selling_price, 2) }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->product_unit }}</td>
    <td>000000</td>
    <td>{{ $product->orderdetail->sum }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Click</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="min-width:auto">
            <li><a href="{{ route('admin.product.show', $product->id) }}">Show</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('admin.product.edit', $product->id) }}">Edit</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But Its showing nothing. After placing

```
dd($orderdetail, $products);
```

It's Showing this result.
[image: The Results of Sum]

So anybody there who can help to solve this prob. I can't able to show on the blade.

Comment: It's Showing the Total quantity column value not according to product_id but I want to the summing value that is grouped by product_id.

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery:

```
$products = Products
    ::select(['products.*', 'sum' => DB
        ::table('order_details')
        ->selectRaw('sum(order_details.quantity)')
        ->whereColumn('products.id', 'order_details.product_id')
    ])
    ->with('category', 'supplier', 'orderdetail')
    ->get();
```

Or join + group by (should work only in mysql with disabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option):

```
$products = Products
    ::selectRaw('products.*', 'sum(order_details.quantity)')
    ->leftJoin('order_details', 'order_details.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->with('category', 'supplier', 'orderdetail')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Many many thanks for the reply. But I have solved it.